# Automatic object creation based on gsp file

Tags: grails, controller, gsp

In my view, I need to display whether current user liked or disliked an article. Here's the method that should generate the output:

```
String showCurrentUsersLikeOrDislikeStatus(){
        String status = ' ';
        ServiceUser user = springSecurityService.currentUser
        Article article = Article.findById(params.getIdentifier()) //how to make this work?
        ArticleLike al = ArticleLike.findByArticleAndServiceUser(article, user)
        switch(al.liked){
            case true:
                status = 'You like this article';
                break;
            case false:
                status = 'You dislike this article';
                break;
            default:
                status = 'You have not voted for this article yet'
                break;
        }
        return status;
    }
```

The `Article article = Article.findById(params.getIdentifier())` line returns null. This is obvious, because I want to invoke the method before user passes any parameters. Here's the gsp code:

```
<g:each in="${articles}" var="article">
        <table class="table-bordered">
            <tr>Article title: ${article.title}</tr><br>
            <tr>Author: ${article.author}</tr><br>
            <tr>Page: ${article.page}</tr><br>
            <tr>Likes: ${article.getLikesCount()}</tr><br>
            <g:link resource="Article" action="articleLiked" id="${article.id}" params="[Article: 'article', ServiceUser: 'serviceUser']">Like</g:link>
            <br>
            <g:link resource="Article" action="articleDisliked" id="${article.id}" params="[Article: 'article', ServiceUser: 'serviceUser']">Dislike</g:link>
            I NEED TO PUT THIS HERE
        </table>
    </g:each>
```

And here's the view render code:

```
render (view: 'articleList',  model: [ articles: getArticle(), articleLikes: getArticleLike(), serviceUser: user, status: showCurrentUsersLikeOrDislikeStatus()]);
```

My question is, how to make the view automatically generate the returned value of `showCurrentUsersLikeOrDislikeStatus()` and avoid the above mentioned null?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the "status" of an article(liked or disliked) based on the user parameter from gsp, you need to make an **Ajax** call to that action or create an appropriate action to fetch the status and update / create the DOM (UI) on gsp after the ajax success on your gsp page. Trigger the ajax call to get data on page load event, so it will add / update your html view **automatically** as you said.

The existing way you are using can render default data without getting any params from user, make separate **actions** if you want both **Ajax** and **rendering model** ways, one action will be for ajax and another one will be for getting default data, if you want to keep the same call, you could check if params.VALUE is  null then set default something value.